How to add return types for EntityRepository in PhpStorm?
I have a bunch of repositories, and I often use methods like findOneBySomeField, findByAnotherField. These methods are not present in repository class but Doctrine can properly work with this.
And here is the problem: as these methods are not present in the repository class there are no typehints for arguments and return types.
I tried to add some PHPSTORM_META, like this:
namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    override(
        App\Repository\MyEntityRepository::findOneByCode(0), map([
            '' => 'App\Entity\MyEntity'
        ])
    );
}

But this doesn't work. Moreower, even if I can make it works, I need manually add all possible methods for findBy... and findOneBy.... But I have dosens (50+ in some entities) of fields in some entityes, so I need too many override directives. And I still don't see any way to add typehints for args. It theoretically possible, because if I have string $code in my entity I should have findOneByCode(string $code) (argument type must be the same as the entity field type) and so on.
Is there a simple way to do that?

Please, include some basic code of the classes involved, and if there are any interfaces being used.

Add @method PHPDoc tags to the repository class.
/**
 * @extends ServiceEntityRepository<Post>
 *
 * @method Post findOneByCode(string $code)
 */
final class PostRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
}


This will work, but I still need add tags for every properties, and I don't wanna do that manually.

There is no other way to do this. You can write some tool that will extract the entity field name and type from Doctrine metadata.

But I would recommend abandoning the use of the findBy* and findOneBy* methods in favor of findBy() and findOneBy(). They support auto-complete field names when using the Symfony plugin for PHP Storm, and the return value type is known to the IDE and static analyzers
